# Tests are got failed in Jenkins on Linux and works good at Jenkins on windows local machine?

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am creating automation script using TestNG framework. The automation script which I have prepared in Eclipse IDE is works perfectly. I have installed Jenkins in my local machine(Windows) and created new job(Free Style Project). In Jenkins Advanced Project Options I selected Use Custom Workspace option. I entered eclipse workspace path as a custom workspace on jenkins. I have used windows batch command for build. Once build is started Jenkins works perfectly & displayed console output which I got in eclipse.

Than I have installed Jenkins on Linux server machine and wanted to do the same job as mentioned above. I have uploaded required files to server & created new job, selected new custom workspace(where files are stored in server). I am using Shell Command for create new build. I have created run.bat file which contains following code `java -cp ./lib/*:./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`. My shell command is given below `bash run.bat`. When I am trying to build Test ends in failure. Below shows the console output of jenkins

```
Started by user iCore Admin 
Building in workspace /home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes
[eNotes] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5444756561147365187.sh
+ bash -x run.bat
+ java -cp './lib/*:./bin' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
[TestNG] Running:
 /home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes/testng.xml
===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Skips: 12
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

All the tests are got skipped. I don't what went wrong actually...
Any help on this...?

Answer (score 0):

run.bat sounds like a windows executable. You'll probably need to create a linux script (run.sh?) which is compatible in linux.

Actually since your script is so small, you don't even need a separate shell script. Just put the java command in an execute shell

Comment: HI, I used the below code in Execute Shell Command. `java -cp ./lib/*:./bin org.testng.TestNG`. Console Output Error is given below `[eNotes] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson984800876131242218.sh
+ java -cp ./lib/*:./bin org.testng.TestNG
You need to specify at least one testng.xml, one class or one method`

Comment: Ok, so then my answer solved your jenkins issue :)

The problem you have now is related to how you're calling testNG

Comment: can you tell me how to call testng using shell command? I am new to linux and shell command..

Comment: It seems like you forgot to copy your testng.xml. In the Execute Shell, I think the full command should be :


          java -cp './lib/*:./bin' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: yeah I have tried this also `java -cp './lib/*:./bin' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`. I got an error shown above.. All the tests are got skipped.. Build Failure

Comment: My answer has resolved your original jenkins related question, so you should accept my answer. As for the testNG problem, which is unrelated to Jenkins, I suggest you try to run the same command from the linux shell, without jenkins. At first glance it seems like jenkins cannot find your testng.xml file because you have not specified a path. So its looking in the workspace of the job by default.

Comment: To better aid in solving this issue, you might want to try posting the HTML reports. They might give some insight into the configuration failures

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX` I got above exeception

Comment: `Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055` exception exists after installing firefox browser on linux server...